# I want to block search engines from indexing categories after page one in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo, noindex

I'm using the WordPress SEO plugin by Yoast and I was wondering if the checking "noindex, follow" under the Categories option will block all pages after the first page in a category or if it will hide the category from Search Engines?

Thanks!

Comment: It adds a literal meta tag to the page. All you need to do to verify is enable the no index then view source

Answer (score 0):

If you check the noindex then the search engines will not index pages with that meta in the head.  So the pages under those categories will not be indexed.